# Treat small arms as one singular concept?

Tags: grammar, usage

Reading about covering fire, I encountered the term *small arms* and according to Wiktionary, it can only be used in its plural form. Now, should I treat this (small arms) as one singular concept or as many separate objects? I know this seems obvious, but let me give you an example to illustrate my confusion: 
Small arms are a type of firearm one man can use and carry by himself
or 
Small arms is a type of firearm one man can use and carry by himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically you would treat it as plural - "Small arms are a type of firearm..."

The word 'pants' is similar. You would never say, 'my pants is clean,' but instead, 'my pants are clean.'